# azure-iot-sdk-c - using the Azure IoT device SDK C in pure statically allocated memory environments

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

is it possible to use the Azure IoT device SDK C in an environment, in which only static allocation of RAM is allowed (no malloc/free)?

Best

Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `azure-iot-sdk-c` was not designed with statically allocated memory in mind, and out of the box the SDK will allocate memory dynamically. With that said, with a little coding there is a way to achieve similar functionality. In the sdk there is an interface header named [`gballoc.h`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/gballoc.h) in the c-utility `include` folder.

By default all allocations go through `malloc` and `free`, but if the symbol `GB_USE_CUSTOM_HEAP` is defined, all allocation will go through this interface. You can setup a custom memory allocation scheme to handle memory allocations any way you choose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, even though it is not what I was hoping to hear! :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe azure-iot-sdk-c could be used in an environment which only static allocation is allowed in.

The Azure IoT device SDK for C is written in ANSI C (C99) to maximize portability. This feature makes the libraries well-suited to operate on multiple platforms and devices, especially where minimizing disk and memory footprint is a priority. Memory footprint includes Dynamic allocations(including heap/VA).

Comment: Thank you, even though it is not what I was hoping to hear! :-(